# How to adjust app size when converting an iPhone app to a iPad app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

I have made a iPhone app that is on the app store. It's a simple view based application. It does have several XIBs and images. I have taken the necessary steps to convert the app to the iPad. It runs on the iPad simulator, but the size is too small. How do I adjust the size of the iPhone app for the iPad? If I need to do it by code, where would I implement the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure springs and struts in Interface Builder.
If that is not enough make device-based adjustments in code. E.g.

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) /* iPad */
{
    self.someView.center = CGPointMake(100, 100);
}
else /* iPhone, iPod */
{
    self.someView.center = CGPointMake(200, 200);
}
```

Typically, you would do that in controller's `viewDidLoad` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you transitioned your iPhones target to iPad in Xcode it will have duplicated all xibs. You can open the -iPad versions in IB and realign everything from there. Programmatically, you can query the user idiom and position things differently depending on whether the current idiom is iPhone, retina or iPad.

Comment: I have a mainwindow-ipad xib, but I did not duplicate my other xibs. Do I need to copy and paste iphone xib and then make the adjustments?

Comment: Usually the migration would create new nibs for all iPhone target resources. Did you use 'upgrade this target for iPad'?

Comment: Yes. I got the xib for the mainwindow. It did not copy my other 2 xibs for the iPad.